# Overlapping shapes pixelated in final export

Tags: after-effects, animation-rendering, shape

I have some issues with Adobe AE, in rendered video (on monitor inside AE it's ok). In the composition I have one shape overlapping the other one. However, the edge of the shape on top is pixelated.

Some ideas how to fix it?

*I use 1920x1080 resolution/8bits color depth.*

Comment: Can you post a single frame from within AE and one from the rendered video?

Comment: I dont know how to correctly save one frame from video file or ae. (Using snipping tool the quality is too bad for recognizing the pixelation) But i tried to export  few frames into jpeg sequence and there it seems ok - no pixelation at all

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_BtMYR6W3f8d0ZMdHhDTkdIbzg/view?usp=sharing @Mulvya Here's the sample video - it's about the blue circle with purple sector - edge of is not smooth/antialiased

Comment: Use Lossless preset or Quicktime - Animation and see if it still happens.

Comment: When i set output module to lossless it renders to avi (100x bigger file) - still pixelated :/ It's strange that when i export it as video there is pixelation but when i render it as jpeg sequence it is allright...

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate chroma sampling as the cause. I'm not sure if MS YUV is subsampled or not. So, try Qucktime - Animation codec.

Comment: I used format: Quicktime, format options/codec: Animation. Still the same pixels --- http://imgur.com/a/Ur9Uk here are some screens first one render to jpeg second image frame from h264

Comment: Upload a jpeg of the same frame as the video

Comment: Finally i've managed to capture the difference: 1st image jpeg export / 2nd video screenshot http://imgur.com/a/yDzW1

Comment: I'm thinking it's chroma subsampling too. It's a very minor defect, and it will probably be swamped by compression artefacts when you do a web version anyway. If people are noticing it, you're not doing your job as a storyteller ;)

Comment: ahh no problem, client or customers won't notice this, but i was wondering what's the cause of this "glitch" and how to avoid it in future.

Comment: If you're delivering the content in a format that uses 4:2:0 chroma subsampling it will just be a limitation of the medium: the colour resolution is lower than the luma resolution. If you are making mp4s that have to be compatible with most current players then that's how it has to be at the moment. If you think that's annoying try designing motion graphics to be delivered on interlaced, standard definition VHS tape. You kids don't know how good you have it ;)